# How to debug python in c level?

Tags: python, c, debugging, pycharm

How to debug python in c level?

in PyCharm,i cannot step into the c level code.

could it?

or which tool can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use GDB, there's a ton of information on it here.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

You need to install the python version with debugging symbols and then step through it with GDB the same way you would a C program.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Visual Studio with PTVS. It provides mixed-mode debugging. [link to PTVS project onGithub](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Mixed-Mode-Debugging). Also, you can download a community version of VS2015 for free.